# Qt Creator: unresolved external symbol __imp__EncodePointer

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I'm trying to compile an empty "qt widgets application" project created with Qt Creator.
It gives me various linking errors like

```
MSVCRTD.lib(crtexew.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__EncodePointer@4 referenced in function _pre_c_init
MSVCRTD.lib(atonexit.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__EncodePointer@4
```

and so on.

Building qt examples gives the same error.

I have Visual Studio 2010 and Windows SDK installed, the right compiler seems to be chosen.

UPD: I have switched to miniGW compiler and it works now. Not sure if that solution is suitable for everybody.

Comment: That looks like a typical linkage error: you refer to some thing defined in some header file (or implicitly) but not implemented in the libraries linked. Find out what library implements `__imp__EncodePointer` and add that to your linker command.

Comment: Well, thankx. I know what a linkage error is. I just don't know what the hell is __imp__encodePointer. All solutions I could find are for visual studio preferences of some kind.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling VS?

Comment: @LaszloPapp I didn't and I don't like that idea very much.